# WSO2 Identity Server without apps in dashboard, even with valid tokens

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I've been working with WSO2 Identity Server, and I can't get the authorized apps to appear in the dashboard. Everything else seems to be working.

- There's a user with login permission
- There's a service provider configured with OAuth2.0
- Using curl, I get a valid token for that user (password grant) for that service provider

After all this, if I log into the dashboard with that user, the 'Authorized Apps' is empty, even though the token is still active. Any pointers to what I might be missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed these steps and I could see autherized apps in the dashboard

1. Register a Service Provider using IS console.
2. Add an oauth2 client to the service provider (Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration -> configure )
   just tick the grant type.select the version as 2.
3. You'll get a OAuth Client Key and a OAuth Client Secret after you click update button.
4. Now, you can get a oauth2 token using key-secret for a registered user. Use this curl command.

Registered user is user1:user1

```
curl -v -X POST --basic -u <clientKey>:<clientSecret> -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=user1&password=user1&scope=openid" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

Then you can get the auth token and if you log in to dashboard, you can see the list of authorized apps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That's exactly what I did. I used your curl call just in case, and I receive the token, no problem there. And if I validate the token through OAuth2TokenValidationService, it shows up as valid. However, the dashboard still says there are no authorized applications, which is weird. Can you tell me which version you used please, so I can try to reproduce it here? I'm using the IS 5.1.0 here.

Comment: I did it in IS 5.0.0. but it should work in IS 5.1.0 as well

Comment: I just checked two fresh installations, and it's definitely a 5.1.0 problem. In 5.0.0 it works fine, so I might downgrade for now. Thanks for helping me pinpoint the problem though!